# How to translate overriden module in PrestaShop 1.7 new translation system?

Tags: translation, prestashop-1.7

I wanted to add some new translatable strings in override of module `ps_facetedsearch` which is located in `override/modules/ps_facetedsearch` so in one of PHP files I have this code"

```
$sortDateDesc->setLabel($translator->trans('Newest', [], 'Modules.Facetedsearch.Shop'));
```

But this string does not appear on translation page ( International > Translations > Installed modules translations).
It seems like translation system is not scanning override folder ...

How do I add new translations to module code override (not template)?